# how to get exact message of fatal error in ruby script

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a Ruby script that take **PostgreSQL database dump** from the **remote server**. Script takes dynamic input for: password, username, host and database_name. So there is chance that user can provide wrong input for these fields. In case of any wrong input I get **fatal error** like

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "sc_development1"
>   failed: FATAL:  database "sc_development1" does not exist

in case of wrong database while we do as,

```
system("PGPASSWORD="#{source_postgres_password}" pg_dump -U "#{source_postgres_username}" -h "#{source_host}" "#{source_database_name}" > "#{store_backup_file_path}/#{timestamp}/#{source_database_name}".sql")
```

Currently I am handling this by checking `$?` to get process status but I want more. I want to get the exact Fatal error message to print in a log file. How to do this?

I want to print the exact fatal error message that I am seeing in the terminal from where I run the script to the log file.

Is there any way that can give me details of Fatal error. I know it's not possible in Ruby to rescue fatal error. As I read [this](https://airbrake.io/blog/ruby-exception-handling/fatal-error) I can print my own message as it handle in case of fatal error but this is not what I want. I want exact fatal error message.

Comment: An error from `pg_dump` with the word "FATAL" in its error message is not the same as a fatal error in Ruby. If you had the latter, your script would exit right away and you couldn't process `$?`. Take a look at [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) – it has various methods to interact with stdin, stdout and stderr. [`capture_3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3) might work for you.

Comment: BTW, the argument to your `system` command is lacking some quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3) module and `capture3` function that allows you to capture stdout, stderr and status:

```
[3] pry(main)> require 'open3'
=> true
[4] pry(main)> stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("ls asd")
=> ["", "ls: cannot access 'asd': No such file or directory\n", #<Process::Status: pid 19314 exit 2>]
```

Do in your case:

```
require 'open3'
_, stderr, status = capture3(PGPASSWORD="#{source_postgres_password}" pg_dump -U "#{source_postgres_username}" -h "#{source_host}" "#{source_database_name}" > "#{store_backup_file_path}/#{timestamp}/#{source_database_name}".sql)
puts "Postgres error: #{stderr}"  unless status.error
```

See also: https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/capturing-stdout-stderr-from-shell-commands-via-ruby/

Comment: getting error as, Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - 
from /home/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:213:in `spawn'

Comment: It's pretty strange - `open3` is in stdlib, so it should be availabe.